# how to edit windows registry so it NEVER looks on a usb drive for its driver (or at least asks first if a driver is found)

Tags: virus, usb-storage

I'd forgive them for this "feature" if the usb standard had been created BEFORE viruses had become prevalent.

Comment: Although there are security implications, this isn't an Info Sec question ,but rather an OS-configuration question.

Comment: That's technically true, but I figured that a board populated by security conscious people would contain at least some members who have taken this basic precaution on their own computers (unless everyone here uses Linux exclusively)

Comment: I don't quite understand, do you want to prevent Windows from searching removable media for device drivers ? Or do you want to prevent it from automatically installing the appropriate driver software if a flash drive is connected ?

Answer (score -1):

Preventing it from automatically installing would be sufficient (kind of like how a browser will ask "are you sure you want to run this java script"), though either would work. If this is controlled purely by registry entries than I could probably just write an app.
thanks,
dsoodak (can't remember which password or email account I used to post last time)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your post does not answer the OP's question and is more of a comment. On this site we value your [answers](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and encourage you to contribute where you can. Regarding making comments you can always comment on your own posts and once you've earned some reputation you can  [comment everywhere](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).